# Etymology of "tüdeln"

Tags: etymology, northern-german

> **[*tüdeln*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/t%C3%BCdeln)** - fummeln, binden; *Tüdeldraht*" - Draht der etwas einfach befestigt; *[betüdeln](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/bet%C3%BCdeln)* - umsorgen.

Einträge finden sich weder bei Grimm noch Pfeiffer, DWDS zeigt ansteigende Nutzung seit den 90er Jahren.

Die angestiegende Nuzung ist sicherlich der Figur *Meister Röhrich* im Film *Werner* zu verdanken. Demnach scheint das Wort wie die Figur eben Norddeutsch zu sein. Dort verortet es de.wiktionary auch.

In meiner eigenen Antwort zu dieser Frage schließe ich auf die den Worten *deuten, deutsch* bzw. Lat. *tueor* "protect" zugrunde liegende Wurzel. Gibt's entgegenstehende Meinungen?

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_de_Eck_steit’n_Jung_mit’n_Tüdelband

Comment: Ich kenne das Wort in der Schreibweise "tüddeln". Dazu sagt [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/t%C3%BCddeln): "von plattdeutsch: tüdern = binden, wickeln, haspeln, verwirren", allerdings auch mit unklarer Quellenlage.

Comment: Wie sieht es mit einer Verwandtschaft zu _trödeln_ aus?

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach so wie *-dröseln*, in *aufdröseln* wohl zu *drehen* und *Draht*, wäre *trödeln* doch sicher bei *treten, trotten*, En. *tread*. Das erklärt aber nicht den *Trödel*. Womöglich kommt da einiges zusammen, einerseits der *Trödelmarkt* wie *Wanderzirkus*, andererseits *Gewänder*, wie *Gebinde, Garne* und eben *Trödel*, ferner *trade*, *traduire*, evtl. *travailer* und *travel*. Interessant fad ich schon immer *Helmschrott*, während der Schrotthändler metallenes Zeuge vertreibt.

Comment: did you look into the 'tüdeln - Tüder - tether - *teudrą' proposal? https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tether

Comment: Ja, dazu gab es einen Kommentar, auf den habe ich gelegentlich zurückgefriffen, der nun aber fehlt.

Answer (score 2):

Ich kenne Tüdel (Kram, unwichtiger Kram), tüdeln (fummeln, sich in Nebensächlichkeiten verlieren) und vertüdelt (verworren, auch verwirrt).

Tüdel doch dieses Band mal auf. Das Geschirr (Leinen vom Pferde Gespann, Schifffahrt) hat sich vertüdelt. Du bist ja ganz vertüdelt heute, Großmutter. Was liegt denn hier für ein Tüdel rum?

Ich bin gebürtiger Bremer und dort auch aufgewachsen.

Comment: nujo, das steht meinen Behauptungen nicht entgegen. Es bestätigt die Glosse "fummeln". Aber danke für den Kommentar. Wegen *Schiffahrt* muss ich an "Tau" denken; Zwecks *Pferdegeschirr" vgl "Zügel"; Weiterhin fällt mir "schnallen" i.S.v. "begreifen", viz "betydelsen" ein, insofern man auch etwas *fest tüdeln* oder *antüdeln* kann. Übrigens fiel mir mitlerweile auch mal "zotteln" und ähnliches mehr auf, noch ohne viel Erfolg.

Comment: Es würde Deine Antwort klar aufwerten, wenn Du dazuschreiben würdest, aus welcher gegend Du stammst (bzw. in welcher gegend Du dies gehört hast), da es sich hier mit ziemlicher Sicherheit um einen nur regional üblichen Begriff handeln dürfte.

Comment: Danke für den Hinweis. Hab ich angefügt.